# Should I use ground fennel in Christmas cookies?

Tags: cookies

Hi I’m about to embark on cooking traditional Swiss German Chrabeli (Christmas biscuits in the shape of a crescent). I’ve read the comments below about the relative qualities of caraway, anise, and fennel but I’m no wiser as to which is the best for these traditional crescent shaped biscuits/cookies. Can you advise please? The recipe calls for 1 Essloffel gereinigter anis. (Dessert spoon ground anise)

Comment: Can you please link to the recipe or at least clarify: “gereinigt” is not the same as ground (“gemahlen”).

Comment: Why did you translate Esslöffel as Dessert spoon? In ordinary language it would be a tablespoon.

Comment: Hi I was given handwritten recipes for Swiss Christmas biscuits by my ex sister-in-law many many years ago. Up to now I haven’t tried this one for Chrabeli. The mistake about the essloffel is mine. I didn’t imagine there would be as much as a tablespoon of anise in the dough.

Comment: Then you might make this exchange of ours obsolete by editing the mistake out of your question. Perhaps after verifying the recipe's intent in an actual bake ;)

Answer (score 6):

Traditionally [Chräbeli](https://www.helvetickitchen.com/recipes/anis-chrabeli) are made with **whole aniseed, sometimes coarsely crushed**. Some recipes call for lightly toasting the seeds, but if you do, be gentle and careful, you only want to bring out the oils and aroma, not any roasted flavors.

If you *have* to substitute whole seeds with ground, especially when measured by volume, you need to adjust the numbers - a tablespoon ground can easily be twice as much as a tablespoon whole if you’re comparing the weights. So measure first, then crack or grind, don’t scoop out a tablespoon of ground seeds.

Personally, I would try to avoid using ground anise, because it’s a characteristic of Chräbeli and Springerle that the flavor is different between bites and the anise flavor unfolds when you bite on the grains.

The Swabian twin of [Anisbrödli, the Springerle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springerle), don’t add the anise into the dough, but get baked on a tray scattered with aniseed.

Here are mine, drying out, waiting to be baked later today.

[image]

If you’re interested in using fennel seeds or caraway, you can probably get a nice result - the plants are related after all - but the flavor profile will be slightly different. Particularly caraway has more bitter notes, but the sugar in the cookies will balance it out. Anise is the “sweetest” or mildest of the three, so biting on a whole fennel (which is also larger) or caraway seed will probably pack a too-strong punch, therefore you might want to start with a lower dose and then crush the seeds.